# Find value in any cell in range

Tags: excel, vba

My script for `Range("D2:D100")` runs but when I enter a value in `Column E`, the script displays

> Run time error 91

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  
If Intersect(Target, Range("D2:D100")).Value >= 1 Then
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    MsgBox "Automated client email Required!"
    Call CutFitEmail
       
ElseIf Intersect(Target, Range("E2:E100")).Value >= 1 Then
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    MsgBox "Automated client email Required!"
    Call WeldEmail

ElseIf Intersect(Target, Range("F2:F100")).Value >= 1 Then
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    MsgBox "Automated client email Required!"
    Call PaintEmail

Else: Target.Value = ""
```

I want to enter a value in any cell (D2:F100) and based on the column the cell is located to call a specific Outlook email.

Answer (score 0):

Your code that is checking whether the `Target` and your given range(s) intersect, is incorrect.

The Intersect() function, when used to test whether two ranges has any cells in common is usually written as

```
If Not Intersect(Range("A"), Range("B")) Is Nothing Then
...
```

Note the double negation `Not` and `Is Nothing`. This turns the check into a positive check meaning: "If Range(A) and Range(B) intersect then do ..."

Your first test should therefore be:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D2:D100")) Is Nothing Then
    'do something
```

The second test should be:

```
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("E2:E100")) Is Nothing Then
    'do something else
```

And the last one:

```
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("F2:F100")) Is Nothing Then
    'do something else
```